# Computing remainder mod 3: Why/how does below procedure work?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

One [stack**overflow** question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76064709/3789665) asks how to check divisibility of a natural number $n$ by 3 with a processor using binary arithmetic mod $2^8$, no divide/modulus instruction (some models not supporting multiplication).
(More fluent with the two's complement, shift&mask notation, below $D\div
d$ is $\lfloor D/d\rfloor$.)

Revisiting computation of a number $s<2^4, s \equiv n \mod (2^4-1)$, it occurred to me that computing $h = n\div 2^4, l = n\mod 2^4, S' = ((h+l)*2^4+(l+h)\mod2^8$, $S'\div 2^4$ already is one such $s$.

I tinkered around wanting to repeat that trick, and found (by exhaustive test) that not just
$(S' + S'\div 2^2)\div2^4\mod 4\equiv n \mod 3$, but
$5S'\div2^6\mod 4$, too (more convenient later on).

Why does $S'\mod 2^4$ not interfere?
How to understand/argue/prove this?

I spent hours to no avail.

Comment: Just to be sure : is $a\div b$ the integer part of $a/b$ ?

Comment: This notation is correct, in competition with $\lfloor a/b \rfloor$

Comment: Note that $5\equiv1\pmod4$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner there is a $\div 2^6$ in between - equivalently, $(5S'\mod 2^8)\div 2^6$.

Comment: I don't understand your question. But, if you want check the divisibility of a binary number by 3, just add the digits on odd places and even places separately, and see if their difference is 0.

Comment: Remember that in decimal you can get a number mod $9$ just by adding together the digits (and repeating if necessary), which works because $10\equiv1 \bmod 9$. Similarly, in base $4=2^2$, adding together digits does not change the residue $\bmod 3$ because $4\equiv1 \bmod 3$, and the same goes for base $2^4$ or $2^8$. Your $S'$ satisfies $S'\div 2^4=h+l$, which is just the sum of digits base $2^8$. And $(S' + S'\div 4)\div4^2\bmod 4$ is essentially writing $h+l$ in base 4, and adding together its two digits. Same with $(4+1)S'\div4^3\mod 4$.

Comment: @DS 0 mod 3. I'm not out of procedures to compute remainder/establish divisibility: I don't *understand* why one step of the (fast!) procedure described above works/doesn't need to mask of "unwarranted" bits.

Comment: The thing is that the sum of two digits may be more than a single digit number. For example, in base $10$, you have $78\equiv 7+8=15\equiv1+5=6 \bmod 9$. Instead of taking two steps to simplify it down to a single digit, you can do $7878+787=8665$ and take one of the middle digits, or similarly $7878+78780=86658$. When you do the sum, those columns have $7+8$ or $8+7$ plus any carry from a similar column to its right.

Comment: So? You only need two adjacent columns where the two digits are added, so $343?+0343$ or $343?+343?0$ work just fine regardless of the digit value at the question mark.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151738/discussion-between-greybeard-and-jaap-scherphuis).